# How to fix this Mysql query that generates error "TypeError: Cannot read property"

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am have a error in Mysql query.

When i use `" companyid = ' + '187' + ' "` is ok, but when i use the variable, occur a error.

```
let query ='SELECT codigo, mensagem, celular, companyid, NumeroCampanha, enviado, Codigo_random, Prioridade FROM Tbl_Email_mensagens WHERE  Prioridade = '  + '2' +  ' AND companyid = ' + '187' + ' AND enviado= ' + '0' +' ORDER BY Codigo_random  LIMIT 1';
```

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

The variable "Empresa" is showing console.

```
let query ='SELECT codigo, mensagem, celular, companyid, NumeroCampanha, enviado, Codigo_random, Prioridade FROM Tbl_Email_mensagens WHERE  Prioridade = '  + '2' +  ' AND companyid = ' + Empresa + ' AND enviado= ' + '0' +' ORDER BY Codigo_random  LIMIT 1';
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you've shown is trying to use the property `0` of anything, so we can't help you. We need to see the code the error is actually in.

Comment: **However**, using string concatenation to put values into an SQL query is a **very bad idea** 99.99999% of the time. Use a parameterized query. Whatever MySQL library you're using will have a way to do that. Look for a way that has you supply the query with placeholders in it (question marks or names in a special format), and then has you supply the values for those placeholders separately, typically as an array or object. Obligatory link: https://bobby-tables.com.

Comment: Please, How to write this query in a parameterized query?

Comment: Again: Refer to the documentation of the library you're using to query MySQL. There are several of them, and the details vary.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
Thanks! Resolved. 
let query ='SELECT codigo, mensagem, celular, companyid, NumeroCampanha, enviado, Codigo_random, Prioridade FROM Tbl_Email_mensagens WHERE  Prioridade = '  + '2' +  ' AND companyid =? AND enviado= ' + '0' +' ORDER BY Codigo_random  LIMIT 1';

    dbo.query(query,Empresa, (err, result) => {      ... etc

Comment: Great! Note that there's some unnecessary concatenation going on there. No need for `Prioridade = ' + '2' + ' AND`, just do `Prioridade = 2 AND` (etc.).

Comment: It's probably best to delete this question with the "delete" link under it. Happy coding!